# Регулярное выражение по поиску номера телефона в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Нашел на просторах интернета регулярное выражение по поиску российских номеров телефона:

```
^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$
```

Автором сказано, что пропускает следующие номера:

```
Зеленый свет для:
+79261234567
89261234567
79261234567
+7 926 123 45 67
8(926)123-45-67
123-45-67
9261234567
79261234567
(495)1234567
(495) 123 45 67
89261234567
8-926-123-45-67
8 927 1234 234
8 927 12 12 888
8 927 12 555 12
8 927 123 8 123
```

Но когда проверяю, метод `re.findall()` возвращает пустой список:

```
string = '89261234567 Nomer Nomer'
print(re.findall(r"^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$", string))
output: []
```

И не могу понять, что не так. Может я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Символ `^` в начале означает, что строка по шаблону будет идти включая первым символ, а символ `$` в конце означает, что включительно до последнего, т.е. регулярка **ищет по полному совпадению** строки

```
r"^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$"
#^^^                                               ^^^
```

**Вам нужно просто убрать эти символы.**

Кст, `findall` при поиске выделяет в результате группы захваченных символов (круглые скобки), поэтому результат будет несколько неожиданный (для вашего примера `[('8', '8', '926')]`).

Решением будет использовать `finditer`:

```
string = '89261234567 Nomer Nomer'
items = [
    m.group()
    for m in re.finditer(r"((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}", string)
]
print(items)
# ['89261234567 ']
```

Или сделать группы игнорируемыми, для этого нужно перед каждой круглой скобкой (но не экранируемой!) добавить `?:`:

```
string = '89261234567 Nomer Nomer'
print(re.findall(r"(?:(?:8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(?:\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}", string))
#                  ^^^^^^              ^^^
# ['89261234567 ']
```